# docker inside container no longer works

Tags: image, docker, containers

previously, prior to a docker update, i think, i would build an docker image and then tunnel in locally with the below command. it has always worked. but now, it doesn't.

this code worked (to tunnel into a local directory on my computer so the docker can access it)

```
docker run -it  -v [directory]:/inside-container [image id]  bash
```

now, it throws this error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

i cannot understand what changed.
any suggestions?

Comment: #1 could you share us the image you are testing?  #2 what is your goal? Enter to the container?

Comment: Is it related to this ? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6680 , if yes, you need to update it again.

Comment: What docker version are you using? `docker --version`

Comment: you are correct. i needed to update it again. now my old code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were issues with the versioning of docker, and when i got the latest updated, everything worked again.  very strange that exactly the same code-line didn't run on a prior version. i'm not sure how i feel about all that, but it's corrected now on version: Docker version 19.03.13

Answer (score 0):

> A "reference" is a pointer to an image.
> "Invalid reference format" error frequently happens when an invalid arg gets parsed as the image name or invalid characters from copy/pasting from a source that changes dashes and quotes.
> https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow-lightning.html#29

Doesn't your dir contain spaces?
Double-check the syntax, like quotes, hidden symbols etc.